# javascript function that runs only for clicked element in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Im using the youtube api to search for videos. The information gets displayed perfectly on the page similiar to the youtube page layout. I have a function that when each div is clicked it will create an iframe fixed to the top of the page playing the video that was clicked, but my problem is making the function work for only the div that is clicked. I know if i put the function under the iframe function comment it will create an iframe for each object so if maxResults is 10 it will create 10 iframes. How do i go about so the function only gets the videoId from the video clicked and uses it to make an iframe? I've tried using *this* and playing with variable scope but no luck

```
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10,
    forUserName: '',
    key: key},
    function (data){

         for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {

            var qImg = data.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            var qtitle = data.items[i].snippet.title;
            var qId = data.items[i].id.videoId;
            var x = qId;
            var output = "<li  class='flex-1'><div class='gridfront' style='background-image: url("+qImg+")'><p class='qtitle'>"+qtitle+"</p></div><div class='gridback'><p>"+data.items[i].snippet.description+"</p><span>"+data.items[i].snippet.channelTitle+"</span></div></li>";
            $('#youtube-container').append(output);

                //iframe function


         }
         $('.flex-1').on('click', function (e) {
            var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
                ifrm.id = "video"; 
                $('#video').attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+qId);
                $('#video').attr("allowfullscreen", true);
                $('#video').attr("frameborder", 0);
         })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one) for `.on()` to call click handler at most once for each `.flex-1` element; `class` for `id` at `iframe` element to prevent setting duplicate `id` `"video"` in `document`.

Edit, Updated

Also, `qId` is not defined in click handler; you should be able to attach `click` event in `for` loop

```
var output = "<li  class='flex-1'><div class='gridfront' style='background-image: url("+qImg+")'><p class='qtitle'>"+qtitle+"</p></div><div class='gridback'><p>"+data.items[i].snippet.description+"</p><span>"+data.items[i].snippet.channelTitle+"</span></div></li>";

$(output).one('click', function (e) {
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
  ifrm.className = "video"; 
  $('#video').attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+qId);
  $('#video').attr("allowfullscreen", true);
  $('#video').attr("frameborder", 0);
})

$('#youtube-container').append(output);
```

```js
var ul = $("ul")

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ul.append("<li class=flex-1><div>" + i + "</div></li>")
}

$(".flex-1").one("click", function() {
  alert($(this).index())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this but when i click on the divs, nothing happens. Although by just switching the iframe id to classname it works except it makes the iframe using only the last video Id on the list no matter on which div i click on

Comment: @J.E. `html` actually contains extra closing `</div>` tag? `<li>` contains at least two `div` elements, which `div` should have `click` event ?

Comment: the li tag. I have a <ul id="youtube-container"> where im appending the results. and inside the <li> are the two divs which im using to make a 3d flipping effect so on the front it displays the video image as the background with the title and when you hover over it, it flips around showing the video description on the back

Comment: @J.E. Which `div` should have `click` event attached?